# @font-face won't show my police

Tags: font-face

I'm starting to learn `html` and `css`,
tried to use `font-face` command to show a police 
downloaded from font squirrel: I'm starting to loose hope.
Overlooked in the forum searching for an answer but 
my will is tired actually.

Pathway:

[image: Pathway]

`css` file:

[image: css file]

Please help me, even tho I might have been mistaking
as the beginner I am... Thanks.

Comment: Jesus Christ, I understood my mistake : sometimes asking the question helps you going further...

For those experiencing the same problem, the '*' before fontface was the hit.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's great that you've found the reason for your issue. Please let me give you just 2 advices for your next question: 1) Please insert your code directly instead as an image. 2) If you've found the solution then you can also write an answer below. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for welcoming me, guess the forum is going to help me sooner than later. I take those advices and I'm writing the answer - even tho it's a shameful one '-_-. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, font was not shown because I putted the '*' mark before font-face while it should have been before the font family entry.